# What is direct 2D rendering in Browser

Tags: internet-explorer-9

What is direct 2D rendering in Browser..

This is the new feature in IE9 that discussed in PDC

Comment: Small nitpick: it's Direct2D, not Direct 2D

Answer (score 2):

[Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370990%28VS.85%29.aspx)

From Wikipedia:

> Direct2D is a 2D and vector graphics
>   application programming interface
>   (API) designed by Microsoft and
>   implemented in Windows 7 and Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, and also Windows Vista
>   and Windows Server 2008 (with Platform
>   Update installed).
>
> Direct2D is designed to be fast with
>   support for hardware acceleration
>   through compatible graphics cards. It
>   provides high quality immediate
>   rendering of 2D graphics while
>   maintaining interoperability with
>   GDI/GDI+ and Direct3D/DirectDraw.
>
> Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox will
>   use Direct2D and DirectWrite for
>   better performance.